# Help with my application please! Can’t open image(s) with error: External component has thrown an exception…

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I have an application written in C# I believe and it adds images to a SQL Server 2005 Database. It requires .NET 3.5 to be installed on my computer. I installed .NET 3.5 and setup a database. It runs fine but then once it gets to image 100 when running on one computer, It stops and gives me this error: Can't open image(s) with error: External component has thrown an exception....

When I run the program on my own computer I am able to reach 300 images but then it stops after 300 images and gives me Can't open image(s) with error: External component has thrown an exception.... error once again.

please help!

Heres a stack:

See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.String.GetStringForStringBuilder(String value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Int32 capacity)
   at System.Text.StringBuilder..ctor(String value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Int32 capacity)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_WindowText()
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.get_WindowText()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_CacheTextInternal(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PerformLayout(LayoutEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.System.Windows.Forms.Layout.IArrangedElement.PerformLayout(IArrangedElement affectedElement, String affectedProperty)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Layout.LayoutTransaction.DoLayout(IArrangedElement elementToLayout, IArrangedElement elementCausingLayout, String property)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnResize(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 clientWidth, Int32 clientHeight)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll

Comment: Based on the fact that you don't seem to have code and only "think" that the application is written in C#, I'm guessing you didn't write it.  The only way that you are going to get a fix is to contact the author of the program.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have more information about the stack trace when the exception is thrown?  From your description it sounds like a resource is not getting closed or disposed properly and is eventually running out of resources.

Edit: After seeing your stack trace it confirmed my suspicion that a resource was not being handled properly and it's running the system low on memory. As suggested in the comments you should contact the builder of the program and suggest that they debug it using a profiler and properly dispose of the objects, or to let them go out of scope so the garbage collector can dispose of them. Also you might suggest that if the error is occurring when a file is being loaded that they load the file via a stream using buffers rather than loading the whole file into memory at one time, and then release it after it is no longer needed.